# Why do I get command not found for 'ls' when using '$?'?

Tags: zsh, exit-status

### Assignment problem:

Execute 'good' and 'ls' in the terminal and check execution status

**What I did**

`good;$?`

output:

```
zsh: command not found: good
zsh: command not found: 127
```

`ls;$?`

output:

```
quiz.sh
zsh: command not found: 0
```

If this command exists then why do I get command not found for 'ls'?

Comment: What do you think `$?` should do here?

Comment: @ikkachu it shows the execution status of the previous command. but I the doubt was related to command not found printing always! wasn't expecting this will be a -2 level question tough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't get “command not found” for `ls`. You can see the output of `ls` right there. You got `command not found` for `0`, which is what `$?` expands to.

`$?` is the status of the previous command. After running `ls`, the status is 0 because there were no errors. After running `good`, the status is 127, which is the status that shells use when a command is not found.

If you want to display the status, you need to tell the shell that what you want to do is display it. That's exactly what the `echo` command is for.

```
good; echo $?
ls; echo $?
```

Comment: thank you for clearing the concept :)

Answer (score 0):

`$?` is the return code of the previous command. If you want to *see* it, you need to `echo $?`. It's normally used in `if` statements (where `0` = true, sadly).

Comment: A pecularity in UNIX since mid 70s (or earlier) : 0 as exit value from a process is defined as signalling good status (though  no guarantees that the run gave a sane output.)

Comment: Not really peculiar. It is not intended to be Boolean: it is an enumeration of possible error states, of which 0 is No Error. There is usually only one way to be right, and a dozen ways to be wrong.